# Python design for calling functions with different signatures

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I have a parent class P with a method `main` that implements the core functionality of the class. `main` itself calls a function defined in another module called `parent_function`, with signature `parent_function(x, y)`.

e.g.

```
from my_module import parent_function

class P:
    def main():
        # do something
        x = P.calc_x()
        y = P.calc_y()
        z = P.calc_z()

        # execute `parent_function`
        parent_function(x,y)
        
        # do more things
```

Now suppose I have a child class C which differs from P by calling `child_function`, with signature `child_function(x,y,z)`, instead of `parent_function(x,y)`. To call `child_function` with its different signature, I have to rewrite the whole of the main method, changing just one line

e.g.

```
from my_module import child_function

class C(P):
    def main():
        # do something
        x = P.calc_x()
        y = P.calc_y()
        z = P.calc_z()

        # execute `child_function`
        child_function(x,y,z)

        # do more things
```

This is a violation of the DRY principle.

**How can I redesign the code to avoid rewriting the whole `main` method?**

Some ideas:

- Turn `parent_function`, `child_function` into methods of P / C, set `z` as an instance variable so the signatures of the two methods can be the same. I dislike this solution as in my case it does not make sense for `z` to be an instance variable.
- Store the output `(x,y,z)` into a dictionary, change the signature of `parent/child_function` to accept `**kwargs`, and ignore unused kwargs in `parent_function`.

Comment: you could have a `call_important_function(self, x, y, z)` method (or `(self, **kwargs)`) on `P` that is responsible for calling the appropriate function with necessary args. Then in `main` you can call `self.call_important_function(<all the args>)` and just override `call_important_function` in sub-classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing the parent / child function (which may be library functions, which you can't change), you may create a wrapper for those calls in you class.

```py
def parent_function(x, y):
    print("parent", x, y)

def child_function(x, y, z):
    print("child", x, y, z)


class P:

    @staticmethod
    def calc_x():
        return 1
    
    @staticmethod
    def calc_y():
        return 2
    
    @staticmethod
    def calc_z():
        return 3

    @classmethod
    def internal_call(cls, args):
        parent_function(args[0], args[1])

    @classmethod
    def get_data(cls):
        x = P.calc_x()
        y = P.calc_y()
        return [x, y]
    
    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        args = cls.get_data()

        cls.internal_call(args)

class C(P):

    @classmethod
    def internal_call(cls, args):
        child_function(args[0], args[1], args[2])

    @classmethod
    def get_data(cls):
        x = P.calc_x()
        y = P.calc_y()
        z = P.calc_z()
        return [x, y, z]
    
P.main()
C.main()
```

So that, you overwrite the way to get input data, and which function to forward it to, but not the overall logic of the main function.

Comment: I don't see how `internal_call(args)` can work. There is no function with that name.

Comment: @quamrana the function is defined in the code sample. It's simply used to have a common interface in parent and child code.

Comment: There is no function called `internal_call()`. I've tried essentially what you have above and I get: `NameError: name 'internal_call' is not defined`

Comment: And there is no function called `get_data()`. If I call `P.main()` I get: `NameError: name 'get_data' is not defined`

Comment: Indeed I want a little fast and did not make a runnable code. I updated it so it can run.

Answer (score 0):

You were a bit vague when you told us
about the 2- & 3- argument parent & child functions.
More context would allow for better answers.

As presented, the code appears to want an optional unused arg
in the signature:

```
def parent_function(x, y, z=None):
    ...
```

Then you could assign `fn = parent_function` (or child_function)
and safely call `fn(x, y, z)`.
Or do the same thing via inheritance.
Your remark about using `**kwargs` amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can just extract your `main()` function into its own function, but pass in the class that calls the function for a callback:

```py
class P:
    def main():
        main(P)
    def call_my_module_function(x, y, _):
        parent_function(x,y)

class C(P):
    def main():
        main(C)
    def call_my_module_function(x, y, z):
        child_function(x,y,z)
        
def main(C):
        # do something
        x = C.calc_x()
        y = C.calc_y()
        z = C.calc_z()

        # execute `parent_function`
        C.call_my_module_function(x, y, z)

        # do more things
```